# Execute command with arguments ends with: error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, svn

I have some trouble with my code to run a program on Windows command line.
My intension is to update a version control repository with the svn.exe.
This program needs the `update -u` parameter and the path to the repository (e.g. C:\Projects\Reposirtory). 
When I execute the code as seen below I get this error:

> Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\svn status -u
>   "C:\Projects\Reposirtory"": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot
>   find the file specified

```
public void checkUpdates(String baseDir)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try
        {

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\SlikSvn\\bin\\svn status -u \"C:\\Projects\\\"");

            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process process = pb.start();
            BufferedReader inStreamReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            while (process.isAlive() == true)
            {
                this.wait(3);
            }
            while (inStreamReader.ready() == true)
            {
                sb.append(inStreamReader.readLine());
            }

            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
        catch (IOException e1)
        {
            System.out.println("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. " + e1.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. " + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

When I only execute this code, it will works.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\SlikSvn\\bin\\svn");
```

Comment: Use separate String literals the program name and each argument, or one String for the program name and a second String for all of the rest.

Comment: Thanks @laune. I changed it to `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\SlikSvn\\bin\\svn", "status", "-u", "\"" +baseDir +"\"");` and it works now.

Comment: select the answer as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is the comment from laune. The arguments have to stand in separate strings.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\SlikSvn\\bin\\svn", "status", "-u", "\"" +baseDir +"\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not `C:\\Program Files\\SlikSvn\\bin\\svn`. It's `"C:\\Program Files\\SlikSvn\\bin\\svn.exe"`. Note the extension and quotes around the path to the executable.